# Drill hole through beam support wood

Tags: structural, beam, support

The photos below shows a wood "support block" in my basement, supporting a vertical load bearing beam above.

The second photo shows the support beam in the upper level. The support block is in the middle of the house, on top of a horizontal structural beam.

Question is, is it okay to drill a 1/2" hole through this support block, and the floor joist, in order to bring an electrical cable through?
[image: Support block]
[image: Support beam]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can drill a 1/2" hole through it. Borrowing from the IRC's holes and notches constraints for joists and headers ([IRC R502.8](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.8) and the text that follows in R502.8.1), I would limit the diameter to less than 1/6 of the joist height. I would feel very comfortable going up to 1/4 of the height based on the end notching constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Also, is there a name for a "support block" like this?

Comment: @TotteKarlsson, "blocking" or "solid blocking." Neither term is listed among the code's definitions, where I'm a little mystified by the difference between the two. Whatever the "solid" qualifier means, your giant blob of wood with full bearing top and bottom certainly seems to fit.